# How to read yaml file then display the result in localhost by using springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I'm new to Spring Boot and YAML.

How can I read YAML File then display the result in `localhost` by using Spring Boot?

It's like `editor.swagger.io`, but it's reading a file instead of writing a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson to map YAML to Java Objects.
For Spring Boot create a controller with a `/` GET Mapping and return your html (or use Spring MVC together with a template).

Those resources might be usefull:

- Jackson: https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-yaml-files-in-java-with-jackson/
- Spring Controller: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/
- Spring MVC: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html